# Copiar planilhas de Excel de acordo com modelo usando VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I need a spreadsheet "model" is copied and renamed.
I tried with the following code:

```
 Dim WS1 As Worksheet
 Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("model")
 ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets (Sheets.Count)
 ws1.Name = "current"
```

But then it copies the "model" spreadsheet as "model (2)" and then rename as "current" the first sheet and not the second.
I need a code to copy the worksheet and rename the copied worksheet.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Reference new sheet by number:

```
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("model")
WS1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "current"
```